# «В 99% случаев или в 99% случаях»?

Tags: выбор-слов, выбор

«В 99% случаев или в 99% случаях»?. Склоняюсь к первому варианту «случаев»...

Answer (score 3):

Пишется так, как мы это читаем: *в девяноста девяти процентах (чего?) случа**ев***.

Comment: В девяност**а**, см. напр. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0  (Вопрос № 264921: в девяноста одном экземпляре)

Comment: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=в+девяносто+девяти

Comment: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: "В девяноста процентах" вопросов не вызывает. А в напрямую "девяносто девяти процентах" — 3 (о) против 1 (а). Здесь О почему-то больше воспринимается, чем А, в отличие от "в девяноста девяти случаях".

Comment: Гугл-поиск тоже в пользу О.

Comment: Числительные *сорок, девяносто* и *сто* имеют только две формы: *сорок, девяносто, сто* (и. п., в. п.) и *сорока, девяноста, ста* (во всех остальных падежах). [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/61-rubric-92).

Comment: oleedd, сдавайте оборону, а за это я проголосую за ваш ответ.

Comment: А я и так собирался. Эта тенденция (писать через О) связана с тем, что с процентами не происходит никаких действий, они просто называют число, а не как в, например: *в девяноста девяти квартирах [что-то происходит]*. Оно не читается абсолютно одинаково. Практика, как известно, формирует теорию и влияет на неё.

Comment: Это неправильная практика, не берите с нее пример.  Здесь грамматику надо знать. Просто люди обычно не разбираются в числительных и по возможности стараются их не озвучивать., а только писать.

Comment: Попадалось в какой-то статье или передаче - не помню. Кто-то из нынешних русских филологов говорил, что, по-видимому, склонение составных числительных в русском отмирает. Мы наблюдаем переходный период. Через два/три/четыре поколения (предсказать точный срок, как правило, невозможно) "упрощённое" склонение составных числительных станет нормой, а то, которое сейчас считается нормой, будет считаться *устаревшим*.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, первый вариант: "случаев".